# Dynamically populate a Google Chart with Analytics API JSON

Tags: json, google-analytics, google-api, google-visualization

I've been using the Google Analytics API to get some JSON data relating to my GA account and I would like to plot this data on a pie chart using the Google Visualization API. However, I'm having trouble using dynamic data to populate the pie chart, where I get the error *"Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array"* if I use a textstring.

Using the addRows() method, if I use the output of the variable 'd' instead of the variable itself, the chart renders fine, but the chart seems to have an issue reading the array straight from the variable. Has anyone got this to work dynamically?

Here's my code so far:

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

var list = [];
var j = "";
var d = "";

$(window).load(function(){  
    var myjson = 'my json response data';
    // my json already fetched from the server using ASP.NET

    j = $.parseJSON(myjson);

    $.each(j.rows, function() {
       list.push("['" + this[0].toString() + "'," + this[7] + "]");
    }); 
    // I push all JSON entries from the 'rows' object into an array, 
    // but choose only the 1st and 8th column for the relevant data
    // and format it to be readable by the Google Visualization API 

    d = "[" + list + "]";
});


google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();     

    data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

    data.addRows(d);

    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the answer - I got this working by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708446/jquery-google-visual-api-graphs-data-rows-does-not-work#2708509) answer on another thread, using the eval() method. Swapping "data.addRows(d);" for "data.addRows(eval(d));" did the trick.